# select intersection of 2 geometries, polygon and polyline

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm searching how to have a result of 2 geometries (villages and wetland) which don't intersect.

When I write:

```
select distinct v.name
from villages v , wetland w
where ST_intersects(w.geom,v.geom) ='f' ;
```

it selects all the names. I want just the names which *don't* intersect.

When I write:

```
select distinct v.name
from villages v , wetland w
where ST_intersects(w.geom,v.geom) ='t' ;
```

it selects 231 lines.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you please edit your question to include exactly what it is you are having problems with (eg. are you receiving error messages, results are not what you expected etc...?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE! You have not actually asked a Question! It is difficult for people to help and answer if you do not ask for a specific result. Please edit your question so that members are clear about what you are asking ..

Comment: Could you not invert your selection?

Comment: In place of "where ST_intersects(w.geom,v.geom) ='f'", try "where ST_Disjoint(w.geom,v.geom)". It may be exactly the same but i always shy away from "boolean=T" or "boolean=F" style.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct v.name
from villages v 
left join wetland w on st_dwithin(w.geom,v.geom, 0)
where w.<some_attribute> is null;
```

The `left join` will return a record for everything in villages, but you will only get attributes populated when you have a `st_dwithin` match.  So if you limit to the null's, you should have the items that do not intersect.

Answer (score 1):

IN your query with "ST_Intersects(...)='t'" you are getting what you expect because each village is tested against all wetlands, and when any intersection is found, the name is returned. In the first query "ST_Intersects = 'f' ", villages are again tested against **all**  wetlands, and if any one of them is false, the village name is returned. Each village is probably outside of some wetland, so all village names are returned.

Here's a better way, using a subquery:

```
SELECT village.name
FROM villages 
WHERE village.name NOT IN (
SELECT v.name
FROM villages AS v JOIN wetlands AS w ON
ST_Intersects(v.geom, w.geom) )
```

Comment: Its better to us an ID instead of the name of the village.